# How useful is Hong Kong Human Rights and Democracy Act of 2019 to HK protesters?

Tags: hong-kong

Is US's Hong Kong Human Rights and Democracy Act of 2019 "mere puff"? How much can it assist the HK protesters? Will it get them their 4 remaining Demands?

Here's why I'm a whit, as China is very powerful.

1. Even if US stops all trade with China, which appears impossible, China can survive and trade with other Western countries.
2. [CMV: I support the Hong Kong protesters regardless of what atrocities they commit](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/dy615q/cmv_i_support_the_hong_kong_protesters_regardless/?sort=top)

> From a results standpoint, status quo is the best hong kong can hope for. It has no real foreign support (unlike taiwan), and it has too many economic ties to the mainland. China has drawn some lines that they have no reason to back away from (they wont allow a democratic process for choosing the CE) but they also seem OK with the status quo (withdrawing the extradition bill).
>
> The issue with violence in this case is that it harms their position. It freaks mainlanders out and makes the political climate in china very anti HK. The cccp doesnt have to answer to its people directly, but it has a radical solution in its pocket that wont spark outrage amongst its people. The more violence there is, the less likely hong kong remains as free as it currently is.

3. [CMV: Universal Suffrage should be removed from Hong Kong's five demand](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/czkf14/cmv_universal_suffrage_should_be_removed_from/).

> It's incredibly unlikely that China will allow any real democratic reform to go through. I don't think that means they shouldn't demand it.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to be about a completely different topic than it was before.